# Where do app images get stored in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With the introduction of the new directory structure in 3.1 (i.e. app/assets/), should app images (logo, banner, icons, main bg, etc) still be stored in public/images or should they go into app/assets/images?

Someone mentioned:

> I would be shocked if anything in
>   app/assets can be served publicly -
>   that wouldn't make sense from either a
>   security viewpoint or from honoring
>   the convention of the public
>   directory. Since you need these flash
>   files to be publicly accessible, you
>   should store them in public.

Valid point. Which brings me to the question:

Based on above understanding. What about the app images? If images such as logo, banner, main background, icons are considered public, why is there an images directory in app/assets?

Or should we still put these types of images in public/images. If so, what is the images dir in app/assets used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** I haven't looked at Rails 3.1 yet...

As far as I understood [DHH's keynote](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGdCI2HhfAU), `app/assets` was introduced so you could structure your application in a better way. <del>But there's nothing wrong with storing images in `public/images`.</del> Thanks to Michiel for pointing out that `public/images` will no longer be with us in Rails 3.1!

Comment: So if the assets dir is meant to be public. Should we store flash and uploaded content in there as well? Instead of having it in /public/uploads or /public/flash?

Comment: Yes, that's what I got from watching the keynote.

Comment: If app/assets is the new convention for keeping public files, whats the motive of having the /public dir? Perhaps 3.1 should have removed the /public dir altogether?

Comment: This answer is not correct. public/images will actually be removed, and nothing under app/ should be served by the webserver.

Comment: You're right, I'll update my answer. And of course the webserver shouldn't serve anything under `app/`. Who implied that?

Comment: Considering the webserver (NGINX in my case) is pointing to the public folder to load some assets directly, it's nice to let the webserver handle this efficiently, if I move assets into `assets/...` I'm imagining I lose this.

Answer (score 1):

The `public` folder will the replaced by the `assets` folder. That's the folder that your web server will point to. Files from `app/assets`, `lib/assets` or other places will be copied (images) or compiled (css, js) to `assets`.

That means that `assets` is now considered a build directory, and you shouldn't store anything there - you might even decline to put it under version control, and just have the server generate or copy the images and css and scripts when you deploy.

See also: http://blog.nodeta.com/2011/06/14/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-in-the-real-world/